# How to reach appium server from android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, webdriver, appium, emulation

Within a ReactNative android application, I want to detect a running appium service (an end to end server) so my app knows that it is currently running e2e.

From within my android emulator, to reach my `localhost`, considering Android emulator use `localhost` for it's own network interface, I have read that android developer use `10.0.2.2` to reach the host `localhost`.

This is what I have tried:

```
// iOS/Android e2e test run on Emulator/Simulator with an Appium server
let isE2e: boolean | null = null

export async function getIsE2e() {
  if (env.ENV === 'production') {
    isE2e = false
  }
  if (isE2e === true || isE2e === false) {
    return isE2e
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://10.0.2.2/status', {
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        accept: 'application/json',
      }),
    })
    isE2e = response.ok
  } catch (error) {
    isE2e = false
  }
  return isE2e
}
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
```

I expect to have the following JSON result:

```json
{"value":{"build":{"version":"2.0.0-beta.46","git-sha":"258938ef66a2a49a4a400554a6dce890226ae34c","built":"2020-03-05 23:13:56 -0800"}}}
```

I do not use any proxy, this is the configuration:

[image]

The appium server listen on `0.0.0.0:4723`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4723            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26721/node
```

It work fine if I want to reach another service such as a running webpack dev server running on `0.0.0.0:3000`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30217/node
```

Why can't I contact the appium service ?

Comment: It is written in the question `From within my android emulator`. Yes `10.0.2.2` map to `localhost`, but why appium service is not reachable, while webpack dev server is, and both listen to the same iface `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Servers see the used host name. May be the server can host multiple web sites on the same IP but different hostnames so it uses the hostname to detect which server to use, of course 10.0.2.2 i known known to the server and thus the request fails. Try on your host `curl --header "Host: localhost" http://127.0.0.1:4723/` and `curl --header "Host: 10.0.2.2" http://127.0.0.1:4723/`

Comment: @Robert, it's a webpack dev server, it host only one website at this address. Also, I don't think it is possible to run curl command within the Android Emulator. Appium service was started with `--allow-cors`

Comment: As I wrote `Try on your host` so not inside the emulator, on your host OS. Curl is included in Windows and Linux.

Comment: it is a problem with the Android app, because http://10.0.2.2:4723/status can be opened in Chrome Android

Comment: Have you allows clear text traffic (non-TLS) for the debug build?

Comment: No I did not, and I think this is the problem. (It is not a debug build btw): https://medium.com/livefront/how-to-connect-your-android-emulator-to-a-local-web-service-47c380bff350 , I have tried to allow using this xml config, and building to check agian

Comment: I rather not allow clearTextTraffic for every host

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to allow clear text traffic for `10.0.2.2`,

1. Create an `xml` directory in : `android/app/src/main/res/`

```bash
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/res/xml
```

2. Create a file in it `network_security_config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

3. Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` in `application`.

Source : https://medium.com/livefront/how-to-connect-your-android-emulator-to-a-local-web-service-47c380bff350